# Antonym of 'saint'

Tags: antonyms

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the antonym of 'saint'. The definition of saint I'm looking for is 'someone who is venerated for holiness'. I Googled a little and couldn't find any credible answer. Thanks!

Comment: What is the antonym of toast? Of breviary? Of zebra? Of constellation? Of Mordecai? Not every word has an antonym.

Comment: Perhaps _devil_, _demon_, or _fiend_. Let us know the context.

Comment: I think this question may be an interesting one  if OP explains what meaning  of *saint* they are referring to: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/saint

Comment: @Josh61 'A person who is venerated for holiness'

Comment: Well, the antonym for "A person who is venerated for holiness" would logically be "'A person who is **not** venerated for holiness", which would be teh simple base condition for all humans except saints. So I would call them "humans". It's really a bit like asking what to call numbers  that are not 529.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest [sinner](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sinner)

> A person who transgresses against divine law by committing an immoral act or acts:

It's apt here.

[Saints and sinners](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22saints+and+sinners%22) is a very popular expression to contrast the two. (Google books)

Comment: Except saints were often sinners as well.

Comment: Well, a lot of cops are thieves. Words represent ideas, they don't guarantee actions of any individual just because we label them to be something.

Comment: Just because some things are customarily paired doesn't make them antonyms. Is salt the *opposite* of pepper?

Comment: @Robusto: yet you'd be surprised how many people think that _sweet_ is the antonym of _sour_!

Comment: @Robusto: I never said it was. There are a lot of things where the converse is not true. We are talking about this case only.

Comment: @Robusto: You are [affirming the consequent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent)

Comment: What about "willful sinner"? A sin can also be accidentally. But a "willful sinner" is someone who sins by willing. Maybe I am wrong. who knows.